# Partitioning the hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I just built my first computer and it works (kind of). I want to have both Ubuntu, Windows and 1 other OS, but I don't know how to partition the drive.

I go to "Install Ubuntu" then "Continue" then I click "Something Else" then I click Continue. And here it lets me make partitions but I don't know what to do. I have 1 TB of hard drive and 8 GB of Ram.

-Gus

Comment: It is recommended you install Windows first, and if the third operating system is not Linux (or does not support grub2), you might need to install it second. That is, it is recommend you install Ubuntu last so grub2 ends up been the main bootloader.

Comment: ok i think the 3rd one will be linx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to install the two other operating systems first and then go for ubuntu.  Simply allocate some free space on your drive before installing ubuntu and then start the installation.
You will be asked if you want to install ubuntu along with windows.
If you select that option ubuntu will be install in the free space.
If you want to make the partitions by yourself you can see this link:
[ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Multiple_OS_Installation](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Multiple_OS_Installation)
also you can watch this video :
[www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_trEVXBgLg](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_trEVXBgLg)